# Android - dynamic, not focussed checkbox looks not correctly

Tags: android, layout, checkbox, drawable

I want to add custom designed checkboxes to a Dialog. The Dialogs view is set as TableLayout and the number of rows are dynamic. The normal checkbox is too large, so I created custom selector with different state drawables (checkbox.xml):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background_focus_yellow"/>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background_focus_yellow"/>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_off_background"/>
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_on_background"/>
```

and added it to my custom checkbox constructor:

```
  setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox);
```

If the checkbox has the focus everything seems to work fine, but not the look falls back to the default layout:

[image]

I already play around with the xml and switched/added some states, but nothing seems to work.

How can I fix this, so that my images are used if the checkbox has no focus and that the content in table cell is not so large as the default checkbox?

Thanks in advance,
Danny

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Google-provided drawable.xml for a button-type image, but it does have some additional state information that you might be lacking. Maybe you can try some of this.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/appwidget_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/appwidget_bg_focused"
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/appwidget_bg" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've already tried every state available in btn_check.xml (default layout of checkbox in dsk) and exchanged this with my values, but njo luck with this.